# Automation of google plus/play login using appium

Tags: appium, google-signin

I am automating logging into our test app using Google+ login. When I try to enter the username the control goes to the text field but it doesn't send the text.

Can someone help me with this?

Sample code :

```
           driver.findElementByXPath(GOOGLE_PLUS_EMAIL_ELEMENT).sendKeys(username);
```

Comment: What do you mean by - pointer points to the text field ? Which pointer ? Are you using a real device or an emulator ?

Comment: @Vvvaib Updated. When the above code is executed control goes to the username text field. I tried on both(real device and an emulator).

Answer (score 0):

First tap on the the xpath , give an wait for 3 seconds and then type into the element , it'll work , it's better to tap and then type in such scenarios